# How to control log level when using MySQLdb

Tags: python, logging, mysql-python

I am using MySQLdb in python. And I found MySQLdb can print some log to my console, mixed with other logs printed by me. So, could I offer a logging.conf file, and specifiy a logger for MySQLdb, and then control where and which level for that?

Comment: @julivico，Ok, got it. Thanks!

Comment: cool, can you please share your solution?

Comment: @julivico, no solution. I just find if a situation is fatal, MySQLdb will throws an Exception with a standard error code, which I can google its means easily. So I ignore all MySQLdb log in terminal, and redirect all my log to other files.

Comment: ah okay. good idea ;)